# How to programatically add digital signature to multiple Open Office XML Docx documents?

Tags: c#, digital-signature, pkcs#12

I want to programatically add a digital signature to multiple DOCX files, using the standardized approach of the method Sign() from PackageDigitalSignatureManager object.

As in for example:
http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/wouterv/archive/2007/02/24/Signing-Office-Open-XML-documents-using-the-Packaging-API.aspx

The thing is that, when I user the method Sign, it prompts the user for PIN Key, because the Microsoft Crypto API is trying to access the Private key in a SmartCard.

Is there any way where I can only use the method Sign once when adding a digital signature to multiple DOCX file, therefore the user is only prompted once when signing multiple files?

Answer (score 0):

In your case PIN is prompted for each access to the token. Usually this is configurable on smartcard driver level, i.e. there's an option there to cache PIN value for a process. An alternative is to use PKCS#11 interface to access certificates. This is possible using our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-office.php) product, which offers signing of Office documents  (this includes MS Office and OpenOffice) using certificates via PKCS#11 interface (as well as CryptoAPI).